# Limiting process memory/CPU usage on linux

Tags: linux, memory, process, memory-management, cpu-usage

I know we can adjust scheduling priority by using the `nice` command.

However, the man page doesn't say whether it will limit both CPU and memory or only CPU (and in any case, it can't be used to specify absolute limits).

Is there a way to run a process and limit its memory usage to say "X" MB and CPU usage to say "Y" Mhz in Linux?

Comment: for limiting cpu i found cpulimit very nice f.e: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/

Comment: Do you really want to limit CPU to so given clock or do you want to limit maximum CPU usage and still allow CPU clock to be automatically adjusted by the kernel? Note that CPUs cannot run lesser priority tasks with lower clock than higher priority tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to investigate [cgroups](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) as well as the older (obsolete) [ulimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ulimit.3.html).

Comment: Thanks. cgroups looks like the thing I need.

Answer (score 4):

**Linux specific answer:**

For historical systems running `ulimit -m $LIMIT_IN_KB` would have been the correct answer. Nowadays you have to use `cgroups` and `cgexec` or `systemd-run`.

However, for systems that are still transitioning to `systemd` there does not seem to be any solution that does not require setting up pre-made configuration for each limit you wish to use. This is because such systems  (e.g.  Debian/Ubuntu) still use "hybrid hierachy cgroups" and systemd supports setting memory limits with newer "unified hierarchy cgroups" only. If your Linux distribution is already running `systemd` with unified hierarchy cgroups then running a given user mode process with specific limits should work like this

```
systemd-run --user --pipe -p MemoryMax=42M -p CPUWeight=10 [command-to-run ...]
```

or

```
systemd-run --user --scope -p MemoryMax=42M -p CPUWeight=10 [command-to-run ...]
```

For possible parameters, see `man systemd.resource-control`.

If I've understood correctly, setting `CPUWeight` instructs the kernel how much CPU you want to give if CPU is fully tasked and defaults to `100`, lower values mean less CPU time if multiple processes compete for CPU time. It will not limit CPU usage if CPU is utilized less than 100% which is usually a good thing. If you truly want to force the process to use less than a single core even when the machine is idle, you can set e.g. `CPUQuota=10%` to force process to use up to 10% of single core. If you set `CPUQuota=200%` it means the process can use up to 2 cores on average (but without CPU binding it can use some of its time on more CPUs).

Additional information:

- https://wiki.debian.org/LXC/CGroupV2
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6895
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3388
- https://www.grant.pizza/blog/understanding-cgroups/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

**Update (year 2021):** It seems that

```
systemd-run --user --pty -p MemoryMax=42M -p CPUWeight=10 ...
```

should work if you're running version of `systemd` including a fix to bug https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9512 – in practice, you need fixes listed here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/10894

If your system is lacking those fixes, the command

```
systemd-run --user --pty -p MemoryMax=42M -p CPUWeight=10 ...
```

appears to work but the memory limits are not actually enforced.

In reality, it seems that **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does not contain required fixes**. Following should fail:

```
$ systemd-run --user --pty -p MemoryMax=42M -p MemorySwapMax=50M -p CPUWeight=10 stress -t 10 --vm-keep --vm-bytes 10m -m 20
```

because the command `stress` is expected to require slightly more than 200 MB of RAM but memory limits are set lower. According to bug https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10581 Poettering says that this should work if distro is using `cgroupsv2`, whatever it means in practice.

I don't know a distro that implements user mode `cgroup` limits correctly. As a result, you need `root` to configure the limits.

Comment: For workarounds without unified hierarchy, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/436791

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you should be able to use [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) for this purpose. However, I've personally never gotten it to work.

Comment: The `getrlimit` man page states that it only has effect in Linux <2.4.30 and even then, not properly.